# Can I run a call just _after_ an element is focused?

Tags: javascript, jquery

From what I gather, jQuery's [focus()](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) gets called before the element is focused. I believe this is so because the element's border is different when focused, and [when I measure it I get the unfocused border size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650892/how-to-scroll-down-the-page-when-a-covered-input-box-is-focused/7659021#7659021).

Is there a way to run code right after the element gets focus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could run your code in a timeout handler after a tiny delay.

```
$('.foo').focus(function() {
  var foo = this;
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(foo).whatever();
  }, 1);
});
```

Comment: Hmm. I need to get used to hacks, I'm new to JS :)

Comment: Well it's not exactly a hack, depending on how you think about things. The point is that it puts the code into a separate event loop, which implicitly allows the "focus" event to *completely* finish, including the native default behaviors.

Comment: Testing it now, I'm not 100% the problem was what I thought it was, since this doesn't seem to help (even with delay of 100ms).

Comment: BTW, would a sleep of 0 suffice to put it into a different event loop as well?

Comment: I *think* so yes but I don't know for sure that any browsers will allow a timeout interval of less than some small number of milliseconds, so 0 would really mean 15 or something anyway. It should be fast enough to not be perceptible.

Comment: If you can put together a simple jsfiddle you could come back with a separate question, of course.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4021/discussion-between-ripper234-and-pointy)